# Rows and columns too high

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, dem

I currently have a 5m DEM with 6000 rows and columns. I need to keep the spatial resolution but reduce the number of rows and columns to 1000. I have used the basin tool to separate the DEM and extract by mask to split up the DEM into smaller sections the size of the basins but the rows and columns are still 6000. Does anyone know anyway round this? I think I may be able to use Environments to do this but unsure. I am using ArcMap.

Comment: Extract by Mask should reduce the number of rows and columns based on the size of the mask. If your mask is smaller than the raster, I cannot imagine how that could happen.

Comment: Ok thanks this is what I thought too. May have to check the environments is set to the same as the mask.